# i don't know how to remove [''] from an output random numpy

Tags: python, numpy

currently i have this code in numpy 1.19.5 and i don't know how to remove the [
'']

```
lemo = random.choice(["hei","heo","bye","wm","lemr","men","had"], p=[0.16,0.14,0.01,0.14,0.14,0.14,0.27], size=(1))
print(lemo)
```

output:

```
['man']
```

but i want it to be:

```
man
```

is it possible? and if it is can you give me an example it would be much appriciated

Comment: Did you mean: `print(lemo[0])`?

Comment: Please strongly consider to do [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is an array, so just print the first element:

```
lemo = random.choice(["hei","heo","bye","wm","lemr","men","had"], p=[0.16,0.14,0.01,0.14,0.14,0.14,0.27], size=(1))
print(lemo[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `size=(1,)`. That makes it return an array of samples. The default is to return a single element.